# Stanford-nlp How to get probabilities of labels in CRF

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm able to classify a sentence's words using classifyToString method, which returns the same sentence annotated with the labels.

Looking at the [CRF doc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.html)
it mentions that once I finish tagging

> Probabilities assigned by the CRF can be interrogated using either the printProbsDocument() or getCliqueTrees() methods.

which are

> getCliqueTree(java.util.List document)
>
> printProbsDocument(java.util.List document)

It is not clear what I need to input into those two methods to get what I want.

Sidenote: I'm using 2012-04-07 version to integrate for Ruby using RJB, but for all intents and purposes, let's consider this just in the context of a java question.